# MinGW Windows Cross-Compile Error

Tags: windows, cross-platform, linux, mingw

While I was developing my game on Linux (I'm using an ARM system), I decided that I want to cross-compile it to Windows. Yet, I get an error while I try to link Allegro (version 4.2) to the compiler.

I have installed MinGW32 (x86_64-w64-mingw32-c++ in the terminal) and have moved the bin / include / lib folders from the Windows Allegro version to the /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32-c++/ folder.

When I enter into the command line:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-c++ *.cpp -o W_Survival `allegro-config --libs`
```

It returned to me a linking error:

```
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: unrecognized option '-z'     
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: use the --help option for usage  information    
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The compiling is all the same as I would do it using g++. the only thing different is that I have it set to compile for windows.

Is there anything that I did wrong?
All help is appreciated :)

Comment: did you correctly link against a 64-bit mingw version of the allegro libs?

Comment: Oh my, that did the trick! After I put the 64-bit version in it all worked properly! Thanks!

Comment: Ill add that ad an answet then :D

Comment: do you mind accepting this as the answer? for one, this will help people who have the same or similar problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you link against the correct version of your dependencies: In this case, the 64-Bit MinGW ones.